# Str_count() for a dataframe Error: argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a dataset where I need to count any values that contain the string "E9" and what I have so far seems to... sort of work. Here's an example dataset I'm working with:

```
    ColA    ColB  ColC  ColD            ColE           ColF           ColG                     ColH  ColI            ColJ           ColK           ColL
   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>           <chr>          <chr>          <chr>                    <dbl> <chr>           <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
 1   407     345   381 0               E9             E9             E9                          12 E9              E9             E9             E9            
 2   328     301   314 0               6              6              7                           10 7               8              7              6             
 3   295     261   267 0               7              8              8                            8 8               7              7              6             
 4   163     199   298 0               2              6              3                            6 7               6              6              3             
 5   599     499   576 0               E9             E9             E9                          17 E9              E9             E9             E9            
 6   566     436   545 0               12             16             16                          16 17              15             15             11            
 7   200     168   170 0               5              5              5                            5 5               5              5              5             
 8   617     507   435 0               13             18             17                          18 18              17             16             12            
 9   624       0   629 18              13             0              0                           18 18              17             16             14            
10   177     163   161 0               4              5              4                            5 5               5              4              3
```

Now, if I run this code:

```
df2$Exclusions <- str_count(df1, "E9")
```

I get the following error:

> Warning message:
> In stri_count_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
> argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

However, it does give me the end result I want, which looks like this:

```
  Device  Exclusions 
   <chr>       <int>
 1 ColA            0
 2 ColB            0
 3 ColC            0
 4 ColD           16
 5 ColE           19
 6 ColF           19
 7 ColG           19
 8 ColH            0
 9 ColI           19
10 ColJ           19
```

From what I understand, `str_count()` is just mad that I'm using a dataframe rather than a vector. For some reason it works fine anyway each time I use it like this, but when I try to put it inside of a loop, it stops dead in its tracks. How can I achieve the same result but with a function that is meant to work with dataframes rather than vectors?

Comment: `df %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.character), ~sum(str_count(.,'E9'))))`

Comment: Best way to do this : `stack(colSums(df=='E9'))`

Comment: Onyambu's suggestion is spot-on. Don't use regex for testing exact equality of a whole string - just use `==` or `%in%`.